# $f,g$ holomorphic functions and $|\,f(z)|^2+|\,f(z)|=|g(z)|^2+|g(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

If $f$, $g$ are holomorphic in a certain region of the complex plane and $$|\,f(z)|^2+|\,f(z)|=|g(z)|^2+|g(z)|$$ 
find the simplest possible relation between $f$ and $g$.

I tried to differentiate both sides, but i did not get any result.

Comment: Um...$f=g$ would do the job.

Comment: @Ian: I think what OP is asking is if $f,g$ are holomorphic functions on an open set $V$ and the equality above is satisfied on $V$, find a relation between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: For example, $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=-z$ satisfy the above requirement on $\mathbb{C}$, but $f\neq g$

Comment: Oh, the simplest possible relation that *must* hold, not the simplest possible relation between *some* such $f,g$.

Comment: ${f(z)\over g(z)}=e^{i\theta(z)}$ where $\theta$ is a holomorphic function

Answer (score 5):

Observe that
$$
\lvert f(z)\rvert^2+\lvert f(z)\rvert=\lvert g(z)\rvert^2+\lvert g(z)\rvert
$$
implies that
$$
\Big(\lvert f(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2=\lvert f(z)\rvert^2+\lvert f(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{4}=\lvert g(z)\rvert^2+\lvert g(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{4}=\Big(\lvert g(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2.
$$
Hence
$$
\lvert f(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{2}=\lvert g(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{2}
$$
and thus
$
\lvert f(z)\rvert=\lvert g(z)\rvert.
$

**Claim.** $\,g(z)=af(z)$, for some constant $\lvert a\rvert=1$.

Let $U$ be the domain of $f$ and $g$ which is a region in $\mathbb C$.

*Case A.* If $\,f\equiv 0$, then clearly, $g\equiv 0$, and the Claim holds.

*Case B.* If $\,f\not\equiv 0$, then $Z_f=\{z\in U:\,f(z)=0 \}$ does not have a limit point in $U$ and $U\smallsetminus Z_f$ is also a region in $\mathbb C$. In particular, for every $z\in U\smallsetminus Z_f$
$$
\lvert\, f(z)\rvert=\lvert g(z)\rvert,
$$
and setting $h=g/f$, which is holomorphic in $U\smallsetminus Z_f$, we have that
$$
\lvert\, h(z)\rvert=1, \,\,\,\text{for every $z\in U\smallsetminus Z_f$.}
$$
Hence $h$ is constant (maximum principle) and thus $h(z)=a$, for some $\lvert a\rvert=1$. Consequently
$$
g(z)=a\,f(z), \,\,\,\text{for every $z\in U\smallsetminus Z_f$,}
$$
and this clearly holds in $Z_f$, since both $f$ and $g$ vanish there.

Comment: What about the second solution of the quadratic equation,  $\lvert f(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{2} = - \Big(\lvert g(z)\rvert+\frac{1}{2}\Big)$ ?

Comment: $|f(z)|+\frac12=-(|g(z)|+\frac12)$ implies $|f(z)|+|g(z)|=-1$ which is impossible.

Comment: Oops, how stupid of me – sorry!

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis $a$ can be any holomorphic function of module $1$. See my comment to the question

Comment: @marwalix: If the holomorphic function $\alpha$ has constant modulus then $\alpha$ itself is constant (as a consequence of the maximum modulus principle).

Comment: Yes of course. But it requires some work to go from $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ to $f(z)=e^{i\alpha}g(z)$. You start with $f(z)=a(z)g(z)$ with $|a(z)|=1$ Then you prove that $a$ is holomorphic and then you can conclude that $a(z)=a$ a constant of modulus $1$

Comment: See my edited new answer.